# How to create a managed image repository in wordpress

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, images

I want to redesign my current website (www.ch3.gr) using wordpress.
Since the content of my site will be 95% images, I am looking for a better way to manage them from within WP back end.

What I have in mind at the moment, is a central and managed repository that every uploaded image goes into. This repository can be shorted by date, name, tags etc so I can easily find, edit and select my images to add into a post or a gallery.

Every new image will probable be in its own post and part of the blog's stream. But then I also want to have some fixed pages with image galleries, that their content may change at any time. So I want to be able to do that easily and without having to re-upload the image. An image may also be part of more than one gallery.

I've looked into many different plugIns but I haven't found one that offers this functionality. Have you maybe come across one that would do what I want? If not, do you have any other solution to suggest?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried NextGEN Gallery? It may not seem like it from the outset, but it really is super powerful. I just used it in a very similar project where I've been working on flowing 3,000 consecutive images. In addition to having dynamic gallery pages, you can easily display single images from your gallery in posts via shortcode (Or via an interface; it adds some elements to the post editors).

NextGEN itself ultimately acts as the image repository, from which you use shortcodes to display images/galleries/albums -- in that order of hierarchy.

The other great thing about it is that there are a lot of other plugins that extend it, allowing you to flow your images in a ton of different ways. It also has a really straight-forward interface once you get the hang of it, and a ton of different ways to quickly upload images.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/

Comment: NextGen Gallery is currently the gold-standard photo gallery management Plugin.